# How do I find a Fourier Expansion of a given function over an interval?

Tags: fourier-series

Let function *f* be defined by:

$$f(t)= \frac{4t(τ-t)}{τ^2} $$
in the interval [0 , τ].

Find a ***Fourier Series Expansion*** for that particular function.

I am having some issues solving this; I don't have any attempts because I'm not sure how to deal with this particular equation when trying to define my *coefficients*.

*If* you possibly can, show your work step-by-step and how you reached your answer.

Any sort of help would be appreciated!

Comment: What formula do you have for the coefficients? Insert this $f$ into that and show us where you get stuck.

Comment: Perhaps try Googling "Fourier Series" to have a look at the formula?